# auth.currentUser shows undefined on HomePage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I have a file where I have written all the firebase related functions, including this one here

```
function CurrentUser(){
console.log("auth", auth)
return auth.currentUser }
```

When I log auth.currentUser inside the function above, I can see details of currently logged in user but when I call this function on React homepage, I see it being undefined.
Also I could see the homepage logs as expected if I make any changes like adding `let i=1` in the above function. Wasn't able to figure out what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Code for the call. This is to be on the homepage.

```
const Home() = () =>{
let userName = Firebase.CurrentUser();
console.log("userName", userName);
}
```

Output for when I log in to the app:

[image: output with the issue]

Output when I add something like a new variable to any of the above functions:

[image]

Comment: "when I call this function on React homepage, I see it being undefined" Please edit your question to show the code for that call too. --- Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you show the entire code that reproduces the unexpected behavior in one block? So including the `console.log` inside the function, and then also showing the output you get from both `console.log` statements?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the output as well

Comment: So it looks like `auth` has a value, but `auth.currentUser` doesn't. That is actually very common when you're just loading the app/page, as refreshing the user credentials requires a call to the server and takes time. If you want your app to respond to those change, implement `onAuthStateChanged` as shown in the first snippet here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-8

Comment: Yes! That seems to have worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `auth` has a value, but `auth.currentUser` doesn't. That is actually very common when you're just loading the app/page, as refreshing the user credentials requires a call to the server and takes time.

If you want your app to respond to those change, implement `onAuthStateChanged` as shown in the first snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#web-version-8).